# How can I express the concept of a "one-off"?

Tags: translation

> one-off: (n.) something done, made, or happening only once, not as part of a regular sequence; "*the meeting is a one-off*"

I've been using the phrase 一次性 to mean "one-off" (or "once-off"), which my iTalki teacher indicated didn't have this meaning, but I still don't know what the correct expression is.  E.g., I might say...

> the meeting is a one-off
> 会议是一次性的

[YouDao](https://youdao.com/result?word=one-off&lang=en) gives 一次性 and 绝无仅有, neither of which seem appropriate.

**Question**: How can I express the concept of a "one-off"?

Comment: Depending on the context, it might be better to simply use the negative definition (that is, a one-off meeting is non-recurring), so just say 会议是不重复/非周期性的（or 非定期/临时, if appropriate）

Comment: I feel that 一次过 is what you want.

Comment: Are you sure you want a self-contained sentence "This meeting is a one-off.", as opposed to using the expression inside a longer sentence, such as "During tomorrow's one-off 2pm meeting, we will discuss the budget for our project."?

Answer (score 3):

The term "one-off" is a common term in the UK, Australia and New Zealand. It's also commonly used in the US or Canada, though to a lesser extent.

There are mainly 3 types of "one-off"s in English.

1. *一次性* (Formal, sometimes governmental) activities done, made, or happening only once. When it ends it will not be done / be created / happen again.

**one-off** donation **一次性**捐款 /
**one-off** grant **一次性**拨款 /
**one-off** deduction **一次性**扣除

Chile made a **one-off** cash bonus payment to the poorest 40 per cent.

智利向最贫穷的那40%的人口支付了一笔**一次性**现金补助。

Government introduces **one-off** resident visa for 160,000 migrants

政府向16万移民发放**一次性**居民签证

In some Chinese-speaking communities where 性 is used exclusively for sex-related terms in local Chinese varieties, it's translated differently. In Hong Kong: 一次過.

2. *No corresponding term in Chinese.* Events / things done, made, or happening only once. Not counted as part of a regular sequence.

The concept of emergency as a **one-off**, unpredicted crisis also needs to be reconsidered.

还需要重新考虑紧急情况这个概念是否能被定义为一种**偶发**而出乎意料的危机。

(Technically speaking, "偶发" is not the equivalence of "one-off". )

The meeting is a **one-off**. 这个会议是**临时**的。

(Technically speaking, one-off meeting ≠ ad hoc meeting 临时（特设）的会议. )

3. *只/仅此一** (* = a measure word，e.g. 只此一次、只此一家、只此一件) Something that is unique and oftentimes valuable. If you miss it you'll never see / use / experience it again. You will regret it.

**one-off** design

**只此一款**的设计

New Ferrari SP51 unveiled as a **one-off** commission

法拉利新车SP51正式亮相，全球**仅此一辆** / **仅此一台**

Blur Reuniting For A **ONE-OFF** Show At Wembley Stadium

**仅此一场**！Blur乐队重聚温布利球场演唱会

——————————————————————————————————————————

There are mainly 3 types of "一次性"s in Chinese.

1. Disposable

一次性手套 disposable gloves

2. One-off

一次性捐款 one-off donation

3. In one go

一次性通过所有考试 pass all exams in one go

Comment: Unless it is because it is used all the time in the UK/Australia/NZ and I just don't realize it, I would not say that "one-off" is not that common in Canada. I would agree that "one-time" is more commonly used than "one-off" and that "one-off" has a more casual tone to it than "one-time" does in Canada, but "one-off" does not seem that rare or foreign to me. Anyway, +1 for the nice explanation.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

one-off = one time only = 只此一次

> the meeting is a **one-off**

是**只此一次**的会议

Note 1:

一次性 = disposable

绝无仅有 = the one and only

Note 2:

one-off is an adjective

one-off event is a noun

Saying one-off is a noun is like saying disposable is a noun

Example:

This meeting is a one-off (event)

They call us the old folks the disposable(people)

Answer (score 1):

According to my dictionary, "one-off" is an adjective that means " 一次性的", as in "a one-off payment". It can be used as a noun, that means "一次性事物", such as "the meeting is a one-off".

**one-off (UK) one-shot (US)**

**ADJECTIVE**

- something done, made, or happening only once and not repeated - "one-off tax deductible donations to charity"
  synonyms:

**NOUN**

- something done, made, or happening only once, not as part of a regular sequence - "the meeting is a one-off"

Answer (score 1):

> the meeting is a one-off
>
> 会议是一次性的

If this sentence only, I reckon it's correct. It may be inaccurate in some context: e.g. if this sentence is in a dialog to distinguish it from "Regular meeting" 例会，you can say "这是个临时会议" or similar to express.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, one-off, sounding suspiciously like 'one of', referred originally to a prototype of a manufactured product. The phrase was only later used figuratively.

one-off: 一次性

Vespa builds a one-off, four seater ‘Stretch Scooter’.
伟士牌(Vespa)制造了一款一次性四座“踏板车”.

(God, I remember driving that Vespa the first time! My brother said, "Careful, the clutch is a bit fierce on these." Next second I was in the hedge!)